# Public access to Jenkins on Cloudbees

Tags: cloudbees

I have been trying to setup a link between github and cloudbees to show the status of the build.  But the URL requires authentication to retrieve the data.  I have read the documentation and it is ambiguous as to whether this can work -

> Unless you have a FOSS account, Jenkins instances on DEV@cloud are only accessible to users > you have added to your CloudBees account. However, you may have jobs (or folders) which you > want to make public.

What does this mean?  Does it mean that you need a cloudbees account to get access to my Jenkins instance (without me setting up that user within Jenkins) or that this allows public access without a cloudbees account?

I have tried following the instructions but they aren't working as I thought so maybe it is the first answer above.

Comment: I have a FOSS account, but even there it's not public.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [wiki about public jobs](http://developer.cloudbees.com/bin/view/DEV/AnonymousAccess) discusses how to make your job publicly visible; by default it is accessible only to people in your CloudBees account after login. Currently your Jenkins instance is not set up to allow anonymous access (see the section *Flipping the Switch* in the wiki).

If you wanted to make the build status icon be anonymously visible even when the job or your Jenkins instance generally are not, that would require a change to the associated plugin: [BadgeAction](https://github.com/jenkinsci/embeddable-build-status-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jenkinsci/plugins/badge/BadgeAction.java) would need to be refactored into an [UnprotectedRootAction](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/UnprotectedRootAction.html).